# Getting Document Multiple Times in Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When writing rules for a Firebase Database that require fetching a document from a separate collection, is there a difference in referring to that document more than once?

For example, this will cause a single query of the `otherStuff` collection:

```
// Rules single get
match /someData/{dataId} {
   allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/otherStuff/$(dataId)).data.allowRead == true
}
```

But will the following code actively get the same document twice? Or is it optimized, and only fetched once?

```
// Rules twice get
match /someData/{dataId} {
   allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/otherStuff/$(dataId)).data.allowRead == true
&& get(/databases/$(database)/documents/otherStuff/$(dataId)).data.reallyAllowRead == true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this section in the docs, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits

In security rule evaluation for a single rule, "multiple requests for the same document do not count as separate requests."

Comment: Is this still true? It now says, "Some document access calls may be cached, and cached calls do not count towards the limits."